# If the linear system $AX=b$ has a solution for each$ b \in \mathbb{R}^m$, Then choose the correct statement

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A$ be  an  $m \times n$ matrix  with rank $r$. If  the linear system $AX=b$ has  a solution  for  each $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$, then choose the  correct  statement:
>
> 1. $m=r$
> 2. The  column space  of $A$ is a  proper  subspace  of $\mathbb{R}^m$
> 3. The null space  of $A$  is a  non-trivial subspace  of $\mathbb{R}^n $ whenever $m=n$
> 4. $m \ge n$ implies $m=n$

My attempt.

Option 1 is true for $m=r$, $AX=b$ will have unique solution.

Option 2 is true as dimension of (column space)  $=n$,  which is a proper subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m$

Option 3 is false because the dimenson of the nullspace $=\{0\}$, when $m=n$.

Option 4 is obviously true.

Is my attempt is correct or not?

Comment: If $r(A)=m$, how can column space of $A$ be proper subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m$?

Comment: @YadatiKiran  okkss

Comment: what is the  meaning of proper  subspaces ?

Comment: $V$ is a proper subspace of $W$ if $0<$dim($V$)$<$ dim($W$).

Comment: thanks u @YadatiKiran that mean   dimension  of column space $=n    < m$ or$ n > m $  so  option b is false

Comment: And why is (4) obvious?

Comment: No. Rank of matrix is dimension of column space (= $m$ here) .

Comment: @YadatiKiran i  used the logic   $m \ge n$   if $ m >  n$    it will  not have  a  solution     so  $m =n$  for  solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, no. You got none right. You answered “true” to 1 and 4, but by the wrong reason. “Obviously true” is not something you should write in a handout.

---

Option 1 is true, because the rank is the dimension of the column space, which is the same as the set of vectors $b$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$ such that $Ax=b$ has (at least) a solution.

Option 2 is false, for the same reason as above.

Option 3 is false: if $m=n$, then the null space is $\{0\}$ by the rank-nullity theorem.

Option 4 is true: if $m\ge n$, the rank of $A$ is at most $n$. Since the rank is $m$ by assumption, it follows $m=n$.

Answer (score 1):

Given $A$, you can reduce it to its row echelon form following a sequence of elementary row transformations. If the system $Ax=b$ has a solution $\forall b\in\Bbb R^m$, we have two cases:

> $1$. There are infinitely many solutions

This would require the rank of the augmented matrix $\Big[A\Big|b\Big]$ to be the same as the rank of $A$ but smaller than the number of unknowns, $n$. So wherever there is a zero row in the row echelon form of $A$, we also have a $0$ in the transformed $b$. But this is not necessary $\forall b\in\Bbb R^m$. This means the row echelon form of $A$ must not have any zero rows, or that $r=m<n$.

> $2$. There is a unique solution

So we have that $Ax=b$ has a unique solution, which means the ranks of $A,\Big[A\Big|b\Big]$ and $n$ are equal, because we have $n$ unknowns. As argued above, the ranks of $A$ and $\Big[A\Big|b\Big]$ are equal $\forall b\in\Bbb R^m$ iff $r=m$. This means $r=m=n$.

---

All in all, $r=m$ always, so $(1)$ is true.

The dimension of the column space of $A$ is the rank of $A$, that is $r$. Since $r=m$, the columns of $A$ span $\Bbb R^m$, so $(2)$ is false.

If $r=m=n, A$ is an invertible square matrix and there is a unique solution of the system $Ax=b\ \forall b\in\Bbb R^m$. Therefore, $\ker(A)=\{\vec 0\}$ and $(3)$ is false.

Since $m\le n, m\ge n\implies m=n$. So $(4)$ is true.